# using SignalR for sending real time updates to Client applications

Tags: websocket, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am using signalR library for a real-time application, where I would like to show the real-time status of job that is being performed in UI. Like for example, if a test is running, the status of the test can be 'not started', 'running', 'pass' or 'fail'. And I would like to show this status realtime in UI. I have created a simple application, in which I get the status of the test using HTTP Get request.

code

```
namespace SignalR_server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MessageController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IHubContext<MessageHub> _myHub;
        public MessageController(IHubContext<MessageHub> hub)
        {
            _myHub = hub;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            RunStatus runStatus = new RunStatus();
            var random = new Random();
            var testRunResults = new List<string> { "Pass","Fail"}

            try
            {
                runStatus.id = "41950";
                runStatus.name = "DemoRun";
                runStatus.status = "Running";
                _myHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("transfermessage", runStatus);

                Thread.Sleep(5000);

                int testRunResultIndex = random.Next(testRunResults.Count);
                runStatus.status = testRunResults[testRunResultIndex];
                _myHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("transfermessage", runStatus);

                return "success !!";

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message.ToString();
            }

        }
}
```

Initially test run status should be shown as running and whenever the test run status changes from running to pass or fail, that should be displayed in UI realtime, but I think the way I implemented it doesn't look right. I feel calling `_myHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("transfermessage", runStatus)` method twice is not a correct way of utilising signalR.

Can someone let me know if I am doing something wrong conceptually here?

Comment: Hello. I would separate this in Controller/Manager/Hub. So I would create the Hub and create the send methods inside the Hub and then have a manager to control the "process".

Comment: I have created a Hub with send method inside the Hub, but what do you mean by manager here?